# Cannot add <webservice><soapextensiontype> tag in web.config for custom soap header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I'm consuming a Java web service from a 3rd party company. And the service needs authentication tag inside soap header for security. But this is not defined in the WSDL.

So I followed the steps described in http://forums.asp.net/t/1137408.aspx.

I've created a class file (bberry1.vb) and put the code inside:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Schema
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Namespace bberry1
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Inherits SoapExtension to create a class that overrides certain
    ''' methods for processing SOAP messages.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class myExtension
        Inherits SoapExtension
        Public outgoing As Boolean = True
        Public incoming As Boolean = False
        ... 
        ... 
        ...
```

Then I added the soapextensiontype into my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <webServices>
            <soapExtensionTypes>
                <add type="bberry1.myExtension,bberry1" priority="1" group="Low"/>
            </soapExtensionTypes>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="xxx" value="xxx"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But I am unable to build my website because there is this error:

Error    1    The value of the property 'type' cannot be parsed. The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'bberry1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\xxx\TestWebService\web.config line 11)    App_WebReferences/net/webservicex/www/

Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance..